# SpellChecker Showing Error in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to run the Android **SpellChecker** With The **EditText** but it is not running displaying some errors as follows:

My **Activity** is As Follows:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.textservice.SentenceSuggestionsInfo;
import android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession;
import android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession.SpellCheckerSessionListener;
import android.view.textservice.SuggestionsInfo;
import android.view.textservice.TextInfo;
import android.view.textservice.TextServicesManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloSpellCheckerActivity extends Activity implements SpellCheckerSessionListener {

   private static final int NOT_A_LENGTH = -1;
   private TextView mMainView;
   private SpellCheckerSession mScs;
   private EditText editText1;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      mMainView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.main);
      editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   }

   @Override
   public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      final TextServicesManager tsm = (TextServicesManager) getSystemService(
      Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE);
      mScs = tsm.newSpellCheckerSession(null, null, this, true);         
   }

   @Override
   public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      if (mScs != null) {
         mScs.close();
      }
   }

   public void go(View view){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), editText1.getText().toString(),    
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      mScs.getSuggestions(new TextInfo(editText1.getText().toString()), 3);

   }
   @Override
   public void onGetSuggestions(final SuggestionsInfo[] arg0) {
      final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      for (int i = 0; i < arg0.length; ++i) {
         // Returned suggestions are contained in SuggestionsInfo
         final int len = arg0[i].getSuggestionsCount();
         sb.append('\n');
         for (int j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
            sb.append("," + arg0[i].getSuggestionAt(j));
       }
       sb.append(" (" + len + ")");
   }
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

      public void run() {
         mMainView.append(sb.toString());
      }
   });

   }
   @Override
   public void onGetSentenceSuggestions(SentenceSuggestionsInfo[] arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
}
```

I am uploading an image of the error. Please have a look and let me know why this error is occuring:

[image]

Comment: Did you clean + build? I am not getting any such issue.

Comment: i am getting this issue, i clean build as well but the image error is showing.

Comment: Weird. Restart eclipse. This should work fine.

Comment: this import is not getting recognized import android.view.textservice.SentenceSuggestionsInfo;

Comment: For me `import android.view.textservice.SentenceSuggestionsInfo;` is working fine. I just wrote `implement SpellCheckerSessionListener`, imported as suggestion, and clicked on override methods, and its working great. No compilation error.

Comment: what is the build version you are using

Comment: In manifest: minSdkVersion=14, and targetSdkVersion=18

Comment: will it run on min-8 and max-14??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60439/discussion-between-dhruti-and-sandeep-londhe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manifest has `minSdkVersion` as 8, which won't work.

You will have to change your `minSdkVersion` to 14 in manifest file.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

As [SpellCheckerSessionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/textservice/SpellCheckerSession.SpellCheckerSessionListener.html) was added in API level 14, your project is showing errors.

Hope this helps.